# How do I find a file on my hard drive by date

Tags: search, date

I have created a TXT file about a week ago but am unable to remember the name I gave it.  I would like to see if I can recover it by date now.  I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I am neither psychic nor a mind reader and I don't like guessing games.  What is your operating system? Please [edit] the question and include this essential information.

Comment: **recover** is what you typically do with *deleted* files. So just browse your Trash folder. If you're lucky, and didn't empty it yet, just eyeballing (after sorting it on most recent delete date first), you should see it right away ... This technique works on pretty much any OS ...

Comment: [FileLocator Lite](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite) is free, fast and easy to use: look for the "date" tab. If you were on a UNIX-like platform, you'd probably already know you should use [find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/index.html) with the`-mtime` option.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows: start Explorer, choose a folder where to start searching (e.g., your user folder), enter "*.txt" into the search field in the upper right, switch to Details view and sort by modified date. This will show the most recent files of that type in the whole folder tree.

Similar steps apply in other OSes like MacOSX, Linux,...only the name of the file mangement tool varies.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the free program "FileSeek". Thanks to this application, you can search your file using the date of creation or the date of last edit.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.